# Help in understading this assertion..

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The assertion says: Let $\psi : R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Composing $\psi$ with the **inclusion** $S$ as a subring of $S[x]$ obtain a homomorphism $\phi : R \to S[x]$.
Then by [insert previous theorem here] there is a unique homomorphism $\Phi : R[x] \to S[x]$ that sends $x \to x$ and agrees with $\phi$ on constant polynomials.

here $S[x]$ denotes polynomials with coefficients in $S$.
So it seems to me that author is claiming that there is a (surjective !?)homomorphism from $S$ to $S[x]$ but I know what I just said is clearly wrong (I can understand other steps). I cannot understand what author meant by the line with bold fonts...
Also, when we say "$S[x]$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $S$" do we necessarily mean that $x\in S$ too?

Any helps appreciated.

Comment: Inclusion means injective, not surjective.

Comment: $x$ can't lie in $S$: it is a ‘indeterminate’ (a pure letter) which *can* be substituted with elements of $S$, but does not represent an element of $S$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That makes sense, but does that imply anything about $\Phi$ being injective or surjective? Because the author shows an example of such $\Phi$ as the map $p(x) \to \overline p(x)$ (p modulo some integer) which is clearly surjective..

Comment: It can be either or neither. It depends on the map $\psi$ (in fact, it is injective precisely when $\psi$ is and surjective precisely when $\psi$ is).

Comment: The inclusion of $S$ into $S[x]$ is the map $r\mapsto rx^0=r$. So for example, if $S=\mathbb{Z}$ then you would just map the integer $n$ to the constant polynomial which takes values $n$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Bernard Oh I see thanks, I was misunderstanding a part of proof.

Comment: In France, the notation is less ambiguous: indeterminates are denoted with *capital* letters.

Comment: The map I was referring to was $\Phi$, not $\phi$.

Comment: Ah sorry I see it now. I was confusing myself with notations, thanks!